# transform the header links block to a drop-down in magento2

Tags: layout, magento2

I'm learning magento 2 from the [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html). In this article i'm unable to identify layout and template files even after reading [locate template](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html).
Please help me on how to identify layout and template in the example given by magento [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html)

Comment: I was searching in the magento blank theme, now i changed the theme to luma theme and I could follow the link provided by magento2

Comment: If your block has absolute positioning or have float style - you will not see proper hints

Answer (score 1):

There is no template for the top links.
There can be one, but by default there isn't one.
The top links block is declared in `app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
     <arguments>
          <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
     </arguments>
</block>
```

So the block in an instance of `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links`.
If you look in the `_toHtml` method of the block you will find this:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (false != $this->getTemplate()) {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }

    $html = '';
    if ($this->getLinks()) {
        $html = '<ul' . ($this->hasCssClass() ? ' class="' . $this->escapeHtml(
            $this->getCssClass()
        ) . '"' : '') . '>';
        foreach ($this->getLinks() as $link) {
            $html .= $this->renderLink($link);
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

this means that if the block has a template assigned it will use that template. Otherwise it will be rendered as an `ul` element.

if you want to associate a template to it, you have to add this in one of your layout files:

```
<page ...>
    <body>
         <referenceBlock name="top.links">
             <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">path/to/template.phtml</argument>
            </action>
         </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

And there are a lot of layout files that add links to this top links block.  Just search in your file for the text `referenceBlock name="top.links"` and you will find all of them.

Comment: Thanks for reply, according to [devdocs] (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html), they have changed only default.xml and customer.phtml